# how to generate alarm every time when system date matches with array of dates

Tags: android, calendar, sharedpreferences, alarm

i am new in android and developing application the scenario is given below

a.> there is a list of dates ex  **10 , 20 ,30 ,12, 23 etc**  for month march
  b.> i have to store these dates (using shared preferences)
  c.> **now when the date meets with system date a alarm should open automatically with custom pop up and notification**

ex:
   like if today is 10 march 2014 then alarm and notification is generated automatically

i have searched through tutorials but didn't find any which meets my requirement
i didnt know how to use shared preferences with array and generate alarm depending on date

till now what i have coded is given below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int my_date[] = new int[]{
            10 , 20 ,30 ,12, 23
    };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,3);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2014);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,16);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,11);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,17);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent );  


        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        Editor editor = pref.edit();

        for(int i =0; i< my_date.length; i++){
            editor.putInt("dates", my_date[i]);
            editor.commit();

            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, my_date[i]);
            //Log.v("hahha","chk data"+my_date[i]);
         }

            //pref.getInt("dates", my_date[i]);



    }

}
```

Comment: how can save int array in shared preference with just one key

Comment: no it will only get happened on a particular time which will be static

Comment: If there are different (exact) times for each alert: Set a fixed time, e.g. 00:00 each day, to execute your service, which will prepare the alert(s) for the given day. Would be a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Set the `repeating` alarm for every day at particular time like 00:00.When the alarm goes up just check whether it is desired day for alarm or not.If it desirerd date then do what u want to do else ignore it.

**2.** Save the date as `string` in shared preference .

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    Editor editor = pref.edit();

    editor.putString("dates", ","+my_date[0]+","+my_date[1]+","+my_date[2]........);
    editor.commit();
```

**3.** Now when alarm is up get the saved date  from shared preference

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
     checkdate=pref.getString("dates");
```

**4.** Now check the date

```
if(checkDate.contains(","+todaysDate+","))
{
// do what ever u want to do
 }
```